# Are all of the Oracle exceptions named?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

In particular, I've been trying to find the name of the ORA-0955 to improve code readability.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE = -00955
```

What I would prefer is something like:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OBJECT_EXISTS THEN
```

This seems cleaner to me and I would prefer that. But I've looked in SYS.STANDARD, and it lists relatively few named exceptions. Online documentation seems to mirror what's in SYS.STANDARD. Is there another package to look in? Some other resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not all Oracle exceptions have predefined names. The `exception_init` pragma can be used to associate a name with an exception code:

```
create table tb_1(
  col number
);

set serveroutput on;

declare
  not_unique_object_name exception;
  pragma exception_init(not_unique_object_name, -955);
begin
  execute immediate 'create table tb_1(col number)';
exception
  when not_unique_object_name then
     dbms_output.put_line('Not unique object name');
end;

anonymous block completed
Not unique object name
```

[Find out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exceptioninit_pragma.htm) more about `exception_init` pragma.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for hours and nothing I saw indicated that there were no names.